# How are the 2010 OpenDocument Text (.odt) from OpenOffice and the 2012 one from LibreOffice different?

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, odt

As you probably know when you're reading this question, an **.odt** file is just a **.zip** file containing some folders and **.xml** files.

I used to appreciate this, for I could make a document with keywords in **OpenOffice** (2010), and generate for example different documents with address data online using a PHP script.

The interesting file is **content.xml**, where you can change the contents of the text. Afterwards, you zip everything together and you got yourself a working **.odt**.

However, when I make new templates using **LibreOffice** (2012), the resulting document is corrupted and *Writer* will try to recover it, but fails and leaves me with an empty document.

The file structure of the *.zip* (.odf) file looks the same to me. It doesn't look like something has changed, but it must have. Funny thing, when I use the 2012 *content.xml* from the corrupt document and zip it in a working 2010 document, it suddenly works again.

What has changed in the document format? Is there a way I can still 'automate' my files this way? Why would they change something that is nothing but nice for super users?

Comment: Most likely this will depend on exact versions. So for the sake of your question you should really add the versions you want compared to get meaningful answers.

Comment: I did this often with different versions of Open Office. Can't for the life of me recall which ones, but if there is a 'version' string in the document, I can look at an old template and get back to you.

Comment: all I'm saying is that *if* LO and OOo are diverging w.r.t. the file format, the differences *will* be relevant per version, not only on a global scale.